# Terminology of Spanning Sets

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I am comfortable with the definition of a span, and spanning sets of a vector space. The question I have is suppose $S$ is a collection of vectors which form a basis for $V$. Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then even though $W\subseteq\text{span}(S)$ we do not have that $S$ spans $W$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, a set $S$ of vectors in $V$ would only span $W\subseteq V$ if $\operatorname{span}S=W$

Comment: Thank you. Why is it then stipulated for the definition of a basis that the vectors belong to the space? If we are given a collection of LI vectors that span V then is it not implied that the collection must belong to V?

Comment: It's likely just for the sake of well-definedness. Vectors always lie in the space they span, but the notion of "vector" only makes sense relative to a vector space in the first place.

Comment: Ok, fantastic. Thank you for clearing this up.